# Vue js cannot pick up the proper loader

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm not a fronend developer and pretty new to vue js, so please do not judge me :)
I'm trying to deploy my frontend application (vue3) using docker and docker-compose
and unfortunately facing the following issue...

- Once docker container with my app is starting, I receive following error

```
ERROR in ../../bin/busybox 1:0

Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)

You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

full error:

```
[77%] sealing (module and chunk tree optimization)

[78%] sealing (after module and chunk tree optimization)

[78%] sealing (chunk modules optimization)

[79%] sealing (after chunk modules optimization)

[80%] sealing (module reviving)

[80%] sealing (module reviving RecordIdsPlugin)

[80%] sealing (module reviving)

[80%] sealing (before module ids)

[81%] sealing (module ids)

[81%] sealing (module ids NamedModuleIdsPlugin)

[81%] sealing (module ids)

[82%] sealing (module id optimization)

[82%] sealing (module id optimization)

[83%] sealing (chunk reviving)

[83%] sealing (chunk reviving RecordIdsPlugin)

[83%] sealing (chunk reviving)

[83%] sealing (before chunk ids)

[84%] sealing (chunk ids)

[84%] sealing (chunk ids NamedChunkIdsPlugin)

[84%] sealing (chunk ids)

[85%] sealing (chunk id optimization)

[85%] sealing (after chunk id optimization)

[86%] sealing (record modules)

[86%] sealing (record modules RecordIdsPlugin)

[86%] sealing (record modules)

[87%] sealing (record chunks)

[87%] sealing (record chunks RecordIdsPlugin)

[87%] sealing (record chunks)

[87%] sealing (module hashing)

[88%] sealing (code generation)

[89%] sealing (runtime requirements)

[89%] sealing (hashing)

[90%] sealing (after hashing)

[91%] sealing (record hash)

[91%] sealing (module assets processing)

[92%] sealing (chunk assets processing)

[92%] sealing (asset processing)

[92%] sealing (asset processing copy-webpack-plugin)

[92%] sealing (asset processing HotModuleReplacementPlugin)

[92%] sealing (asset processing ESLintWebpackPlugin_1)

[92%] sealing (asset processing PersistentChildCompilerSingletonPlugin)

[92%] sealing (asset processing HtmlWebpackPlugin)

[92%] sealing (asset processing)

[93%] sealing (after asset optimization)

[94%] sealing (recording)

[94%] sealing (recording HotModuleReplacementPlugin)

[94%] sealing (recording)

[94%] sealing (after seal)

[95%] emitting (emit)

[98%] emitting (after emit)

Build finished at 14:30:17 by 0.000s

Build finished at 14:30:17 by 0.000s

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error2:30:17 PM


 error  in ../../bin/busybox


Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)

You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

(Source code omitted for this binary file)


Build finished at 14:30:17 by 0.000s

Build finished at 14:30:17 by 0.000s

Build finished at 14:30:17 by 0.000s

Build finished at 14:30:17 by 0.000s

Build finished at 14:30:17 by 0.000s

Build finished at 14:30:17 by 0.000s

Build finished at 14:30:17 by 0.000s

Build finished at 14:30:17 by 0.000s

Build finished at 14:30:17 by 0.000s

ERROR in ../../bin/busybox 1:0

Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)

You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

(Source code omitted for this binary file)


webpack compiled with 1 error
```

According to this article ['You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.' in Vue.js project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39059426/you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type-in-vue-js-project) , I need to add some loaders for different file extensions, (i have only vue / js files / html / + images (.ico, .svg, .png, .jpg) and some .yaml and jenkinsfile files )

so to my `vue.config.js` I added this snippet as well

```js
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
          
          { test: /\.(png|jpg|svg)$/, use: ['file-loader?name=./images/[name].[ext]'] },
          { test: /\.node$/, use: "node-loader"},
          { test: /\.ts$/, loader: "ts-loader" },  
          { test: /\.ya?ml$/, use: 'yaml-loader'}
      ],
  }
  },
```

All loaders, mentioned at configuration is installed
But it does not help, because the error does not going away..

Any solutions / advices / tips or other help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you add complete error stack. It is hard to know which file Webpack is complaining about.

Comment: Can you share link to code or content of `busybox` file?